# An int32_t value in the first element of uint32_t array

Tags: c

I have defined a uint32_t array (p), but want to reserve p[0] with an (Int32_t size) value only in the first element. How can this be done using type casting ?.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET server_socket, client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
int c, iResult;
char sendbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
uint32_t* p;
int i; 

p = (uint32_t*)sendbuf;
int32_t size = 160*120*sizeof(uint32_t)+2*sizeof(uint32_t);

p[0] = //size <-- I want to define the value here
}
```

Comment: What difference do you perceive between `(int)76808` and `(uint)76808`?

Comment: Will you ever actually need a negative size value anyway?

Comment: I'm using LabVIEW that receives data from this C-program. Before sending the actual data, I want to send a 4-bytes string length, which LabVIEW only accepts as Int32_t values. But now I quickly figured out, that it can read the same string length with a uint32_t data type as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a `struct`.  It allows you to contain different data types in one variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. C arrays are homogeneous (all elements in the array must have the same type). You can store the number 76808 in a `uint32_t`, that's perfectly fine, and 76808 has the same binary representation in a `uint32_t` as it would in a `int32_t`.

Comment: ... or define a `struct` to hold the size of an accompanying array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you have to understand that `p[0]` occupies the same space as `sendbuf[0]`, `sendbuf[1]`, `sendbuf[2]` and `sendbuf[3]`.  You may want to reserve additional space to allow for that:

```
char sendbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN + sizeof(uint32_t) ) ;
```

It is not clear to me why the type of `*p` and the type of `size` differ, that is an unnecessary type disagreement.

A better approach may be to define a structure:

```
int main()
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t size ;
        char data[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    } sendbuf ;

    sendbuf.size = 160*120*sizeof(uint32_t)+2*sizeof(uint32_t);

    memset( sendbuf.data, 0, sizeof( sendbuf.data) ) ;  // For example     
}
```